# Function description of node js in jupyter

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I want to know function's description, when i use ipython or jupytor.
So. when i use python, i'm use '?' character in the ipython. like below.

[image]

then, I can see the function description of 'os.path'. however in the node js, I don't know how to see the function's description in the jupitor.
who know that?

[image]

Thanks you.

Comment: what if you type `help(os.path)` instead of `os.path?`